# Tools and steps on programming MSP430

Tags: c, msp430, launchpad

Just bought an MSP430 launchpad

Been reading through stuff, but I'm unable to learn from all those verbose  sources how to stick my C program inside the micro controller. They're not objective (I've started with the manuals that came within, then following hundreds of links on texas website. They are poorly informative).

TO BEAR IN MIND:

- I'm a student;
- My professor isn't of much help;
- I'm completely new to this hardware stuff. Kind of new on C programming too... we can say a year of practice;
- I consider the KISS principle a good practice: My teacher accomplishes a firework of LEDs with a .c file, a makefile, and a make.exe that I don't have the least idea of what is and how works.

Below, my steps taken so far: (They did NOT work. That's the reason I'm asking here. I would appreciate a very objective procedure/corrections at first, and later, the brainstorm)

Downloaded mspgcc-20120406-p20120911

Installed that on Code::Blocks, using Settings > Compiler - Toolchain Executables tab

(I've tried Energia, but doesn't seem like a very orthodox .c editor. And I love codeblocks,  or devcpp, or, as a third option, notepad++, or even Eclipse)

I've also tried CodeComposerStudio. After downloading packages and starting a full project answering neverending questions, <s>I still don't know how to flash the code.</s>

I even made a simple program to blink a led:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <msp430f5529.h>
#include <msp430.h>


void ConfigureCpu(void)
{

  WDTCTL = 0x5a80;

// ACLK  = 32768 Hz
// MCLK  = 16000000 Hz
// SMCLK = 16000000 Hz

   DCOCTL  = 0x74;
   BCSCTL1 = 0x0F;
   BCSCTL2 = 0x88;
   BCSCTL3 = 0x84;



  P4DIR = 0xff;
}

void delayms(t)
{
int i, x;
for(i=0;i<=t;i++)
    for(x=0;x<16000;x++);
}

int main()
{
ConfigureCpu();

while(1)
    {
    P4OUT=0x42; //0100 0010 = 0x42
    delayms(1000);
    P4OUT=0x00;
    delayms(1000);
    }

}
```

It doesn't work for two reasons:

```
'DCOCTL' undeclared (first use in this function)|

And if I comment those registers, I get the following:

cannot open linker script file memory.x||No such file or directory|
```

.

L:\MSP\ is my directory for everything related to this journey

Example:

L:\MSP\GCC

L:\MSP\Flasher\

L:\MSP\Programs //my .c are stored here

(Code::Blocks is installed on the root of C:)

I would like someone to tell me what I need to learn (step by step, if possible, from the very beginning, to the very end - from choosing tools, to uploading to the controller)

Comment: There are some examples to be googled. However, this question is not the right for [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it opinion related and too broad.

Comment: Sidenote: For the MSP430, you should avoid signed data types. This because sometimes sign-extension is required and it costs one additional instruction compared to zero-extend (for unsigned). Also, you should use `stdint.h` data types, not the standard C types for embedded programming. Also, the delay-loop will be optimized away completely, as any decent compiler detects they do actually noting (the compiler does not know about your intention). If you do not want variable accesses to be optimized away, become familar with `volatile`. **This is vital**

Comment: I was just kicked out of Super User because my question was "programming related". Also, if you want to help me, you gonna have to go slower: Please, where did I use signed data ? Is this the explanation for the compiler considering the DCOCTL a variable ? why have I never heard about this stdint.h ? What should I use instead of the delay-loop  (apart from the volatile solution) ?

Comment: Ehm.. No offense, but if you're really not aware you use signed variables ([starter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Interface_to_the_properties_of_the_basic_types)) you might get the basics of programming first, otherwise you will really have a hard time. Just a friendly hint.

Comment: The MCU peripheral registers _are_ variables - of course. Problem is: this is not a beginner's couse or tutorial site. And - please understand - I do not have the time to start one here. That would take some weeks at least to get just the basics and I have to work for a living (no Zuckerberg ._}.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I understand. Some details I forgot to tell: I'm a student, and on my professor's examples, he programs like normal c, using 'short' and 'chars' when he wants to spare memory. I'll update the main question with these and more information. Thanks again.

Comment: So please take him to the "new" standard of C99 (yes, it's already 16 years old). There is a reason it defines `stdint.h`. To save RAM (which I completey support) you would use types of well defined size. The internal types (short, char, etc.) do not even define a certain size. So you basically can end up very well wit 32 bit chars (well, on MSP430, you won't, but that is _implementation dependent_). So, use uint8_t or uint16_ for instance. For signed vs. unsigned have a close look at the MSP430 Family Guide (CPU/instruction set)..

Answer (score 1):

The flyer in the box describes what to do.

Go to [www.ti.com/launchpad](http://www.ti.com/launchpad) and download either Code Composer Studio 4 or the IAR Embedded Workbench trial.

The TI page also holds all other information that you might need.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `msp430f5529.h` file on my system, it seems like this chip doesn't have those registers or they aren't in the header. The code just sets the register to a magic number with no explanation, comment, or calculation, so it's hard to figure out what the purpose is. (It's probably trying to configure clocks.)

Second, you'll probably need that linker file for your chip so the compiler (linker stage) can set up correct memory addresses.

The code actually looks like a blinky, but meant for a different chip or compiler. It would probably work but you'd need to change the parts that are different (port it) for your setup. It would be educational, but perhaps not what you want to spend your time on.

To solve both problems, I'd start by getting a project meant for the particular chip/board you have. Build that and see if it works. Then you know your compiler and the project work. You can go on to modify it for your application.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Rough month. And you, sir, are correct ! Those are old registers. They were replaced by the Unified Clock System (page 184 of slau208n). Thanks for pointing out.

My chip is the msp430F5529.
CCS has a better blinker example.
On their example they only #inlcude<msp430.h>. This library loads automatically another library, which is the specific msp430F5529. And it works.
Gotta learn this new system now... Thanks again.